# Prohibit the posting of HTML in textarea form field

Tags: php, html, tags

I have a text area where a user can define a post.  This field should allow BBCODE but not HTML.

Currently HTML is allowed but it should not be.

How can I disallow HTML tags to be posted by the user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two main choices here. You can either escape the HTML, so it's treated as plain text, or you can remove it. Either way is safe, but escaping is usually what users expect.

To escape, use `htmlspecialchars()` <sup>[[docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)]</sup> on the input, before you process the bbcode.

```
echo htmlspecialchars("<b>Hello [i]world![/i]</b>")
```

```
&lt;b&gt;Hello [i]world![/i]&lt;/b&gt;
```

To remove the HTML tags entirely, use `strip_tags()` <sup>[[docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)]</sup> instead:

```
echo strip_tags("<b>Hello [i]world![/i]</b>")
```

```
Hello [i]world![/i]
```

Comment: Well, it won't change the input string, if there is any HTML tag?
I just want to remove whole HTML code, if there is any.

Comment: There is a warning in the manual, which say that using strip_tags can result in the removal of more text/data. Is there any way, to just disallow printing the html tags? I mean, if there is fe. <b>test</b> tag in the text, then after saving, it will just print <b>test</b> instead of bolded "test". I was looking though, and can I use htmlspecialchars() to save the data and then htmlspecialchars_ decode() to display the data?

Comment: @Lucas: When you're converting the user's input to HTML, just call `htmlspecialchars` on the input before evaluating the bbcode. I'm pretty sure that will do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `strip_tags()` it will strip html tags & preserve the text but leave BBcode.